# How to remove Owner access to all users OneDrive via Powershell?

Tags: powershell, office365

I used a powershell script to give myself Owner access to all of our Sharepoint sites (I'm an admin) however this has given me owner rights to everyone's in my tenants OneDrive. I can't remember the script I used as it was some time ago and have only noticed the ownership on all OneDrives.

How can I remove access to OneDrive files and retain ownership to Sharepoint sites?

Comment: _I can't remember the script I used_.. Didn't you save that?

Comment: It was a while ago now and didn't notice the permissions to OneDrive users up until recently.